# Why is it so difficult to deal with cold calling?

Tags: united-kingdom, crime

[It is in the news](https://www.theguardian.com/money/2023/may/02/clampdown-on-cold-calls-and-mass-texting-technology-announced-in-uk) that the UK government is making a significant investment in "a clampdown on the use of cold calls to sell financial products".  This involves significant investment in specialist skills:

> The new fraud strategy, a response to the massive growth of web- and phone-based scams, will also result in what was billed as 400 new specialist investigators across police and the National Crime Agency recruited as part of a revamp for how the crime is investigated.

I have a UK mobile phone, and I get fairly frequent cold calls from geographic UK landline numbers.  If I straight up make a GDPR Subject Access Request they invariably hang up.  If I keep them talking I get all sorts of stories, the only commonality being that they involve lies.  The last one was noteworthy in that the caller accused me of gas lighting them when I read out from the [Companies House Web site](https://find-and-update.company-information.service.gov.uk/) that the company they claimed to work for was wound up five years ago.  I do not know what the scam is, but I am sure it is a scam and the GDPR breach would seem to serve as "Al Capone's taxes", in that it is not really the problem but is easy to prove beyond reasonable doubt.

It seems that if the government wanted to make this activity a non-viable way of making money it would be trivial.  Someone has paid for that telephone call, that entity must have a bank account that is known to the telephone operators.  The GDPR breach seems clear, and the maximum penalty is £17.5 million.  If the UK state wanted to "clampdown on the use of cold calls" it would not take a team of 400 sepalists to  find these numbers, find out who is paying the bill from the telephone operator and start enforcement action.  The risk reward ratio seems so unbalanced that it could be stopped tomorrow.

Why is cold calling still an issue in this day and age, given that the government cares about it?

Comment: This isn't anywhere near an answer, but I suspect your belief that a geographic caller ID implies a significant credit history is false. Virtual landlines are readily available from multiple providers (and sub-providers) ranging from the reputable [https://www.vodafone.co.uk/business/unified-communications/vodafone-one-net-anywhere] to the extremely sketchy (not going to link, but I can find a large number advertising "no contract" options).

Comment: @origimbo Vodafone I would consider a telephone operator, and expect them to be able to provide banking details of their customers.  If an organisation was shaddy enough that they would not cooperate with police in investigating crime there are avenues to deal with that, including aiding and abetting/accessory after the fact type laws.  There is a reason criminals use cryptocurrency, and I do not think you can buy a landline telephone number with cryptocurrency.

Comment: Why would they need a local footprint at all? I would think they'd use [VOIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_over_IP), which is definitely available in prepaid form using all kinds of payment methods that would be hard to track (crypto, prepaid card codes, stolen credit cards). Then all they need to pretend to be local is spoofing a local number which is also [trivial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caller_ID_spoofing#Technology_and_methods).

Comment: @JJJ I guess that could be the answer.  If criminals are calling people in the UK displaying a UK number and that call be untraceable by the authorities then that would allow this to go on.  It seems that should be mentioned by the media in a story about government is spending loads of money on the problem.

Comment: This seems more of a law enforcement and technology issue than a political issue.  Depending on what calls you are calling about, many of them may come from overseas, using spoofing to appear domestic.  Your question is also fairly unclear, veering between different terms:  cold calling - a normal, if annoying and possibly now illegal commercial outreach approach.  And scams - a certainly not legal intent to defraud.  The distinction is important:  a legitimate domestic actor may care about GDPR for example, an overseas fraudster would most certainly not.  VTC, please be more specific.

Comment: FWIW, the US/Canada side of telephone fraud and robocalls was supposed to be addressed by a technology called STIR/SHAKEN.  [This is one critical coverage of it, which has been cited by others](https://www.pindrop.com/blog/stir-shaken-is-not-call-authentication).  Not saying it never works, but... it is not a simple problem, technically speaking, meaning that asking why the &%(# politicians aren't doing their job may be missing the point.  [Coverage of UK specifics](https://commsrisk.com/uk-adopts-new-rules-to-stop-cli-spoofing-but-not-stir-shaken/)

Comment: I either don't answer or I use profanity (which is a misdemeanor). But some people are lonely and will talk to anyone who calls, and they might be convinced that some person they know is in jail and needs bail money NOW in the form of Apple Pay cards...

Comment: @JJJ and which reputable VOIP operator allows buying numbers with crypto? and why is that entire operator not legally blocked?

Comment: @user253751 the one I use does, it's a Dellmont reseller. They also do pre-paid cards like paysafecard. I don't think that's uncommon, so many services have a way to pay online without clearly identifying yourself as the customer.

Comment: @JJJ in other industries like banking, it's totally impossible to get a bank account without submitting government ID, so I wonder why a similar law does not apply to phone numbers. This is enforced because no financial institution will do business with any other one that doesn't enforce it. You either kick off your anonymous customers, or the Federal Reserve kicks you off and then you can only handle dollars in cash form and can't send payments to other banks, which is obviously extremely impractical.

Comment: @user253751 that might be a topic for another question, e.g. why the rules are so strict on banking when they aren't for phone numbers.

Answer (score 21):

The thing about such scams is, there is money in it. And the scams may be originated nearly anywhere. So the incentives are enormous.

Here is a story about phone scams in [Alberta, Canada.](https://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/calgary/alberta-scam-calls-data-1.6767492) In one year the scammed money was $5.4 million.  This is a province with a population of only 4.2 million people. The financial incentives are clear.

The comments have referred to some of the problems. Basically, it's an "arms race" between the various authorities and the scammers. The authorities get a technique. It hurts the income of the scammers. The scammers invent ways to get around it.

- Some phone number prefixes are blocked? Spoof the phone number.
- Some geographic regions are blocked? Spoof the region ID.
- Some other thing is keyed on to detect the scammers? Spoof that.
- Some pattern of scam becomes known? They change the pattern.

It used to be a Nigerian prince trying to get money out of his home country. Now it's Ukrainian businessmen. Or people from Hong Kong. Or whatever place is in the news. Or it's somebody connected to whatever politician is in the news, trying to get his illicit money to someplace safe.

Or it's just a guy pretending to sell shares in a bank that has been doing business for a century. When really he's just a scammer who photocopied some letterhead from that bank.

The scammers are prepared to move to a new scam quite quickly if the old one stops paying. Whether because it becomes known or the authorities get new equipment. Their offices are basically a cell phone and maybe a laptop computer.  They can be out the door and "in the wind" in the time it takes to close the laptop and put the cell phone in their pocket. If they feel too beset by the authorities, these devices can easily be destroyed beyond recovery of the data.

So, even if the political forces are of good will and trying to help their citizens, the target is a moving one. And it is not universal by any means that the political forces are trying to help. Politicians mostly do what they believe will be good for themselves, as do a lot of people.

If a politician perceives his self interest to be in "happy citizens" then he may push for laws that help deal with scammers. And then the scammers all take "one step to the left, one step back, and one step to the right." And set up shop one street over doing "red" scams when the used to do "blue" scams. And the politicians have a lot of trouble catching up.

Comment: "Their offices are basically a cell phone and maybe a laptop computer." This isn't actually true. Their offices are massive call centres in India that have a handful of people doing actual call centre work to offer a fig leaf of an excuse to all the scammers.

Comment: I think it was "Trilogy Media" on youtube (or perhaps one of its members) that tracked down a scam call center in (I think) Mumbai. It was a permanent office in one part of a building that was otherwise used for call centers of legitimate businesses. It was kept hidden from neighbours and authorities too. They delivered cockroaches, fart bombs and hand soap with blue ink. (Of course, being YouTube personalities only, it's not outside of reason the whole thing could've been fake, but I don't think so)

Answer (score 6):

## Frame Challenge: *Technically,* cold calling is functionally the same as just calling a [random 10-digit number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_the_United_Kingdom).

The mention of a GDPR Subject Access Request does seem to indicate that you think the group spamming you *has* more information that they could give you on the request.

It's entirely possible they're just robocalling random numbers in the area, and therefore don't actually have your number in question. It [certainly wouldn't be impossible for one person to do that](https://youtu.be/FO0iG_P0P6M?t=227) on a scale that surprises people...because there's not always someone on the other line. Regulating the software technology to do that would be difficult to do so politically...because the fundamental technology allows politicians to do fundraising campaigns, volunteer outreach, or even political surveys of their constituents - sometimes with voicemail or automated voice systems handling the multiple calls that go to voicemail or can't be serviced by a specific person on their end; they *can* tie the information of a phone number to a name and other information, but that's something that's not inherent to just robocalling random numbers in an area.

It's rather difficult technically to restrict said calls, since it'll be near impossible to distinguish *why* a call is made before a call is connected (See @Boba Fit's details about the potential arms race trying to resolve that), or even if the call being made is not just a wrong number.

And that's all before the scale of the issue - the video I linked was posted in 2019, but it sources a 2018 citation that in a year from then, half of all mobile phone calls will be scams. At that sheer scale, there's almost a guarantee that some of those calls (If not most of them), aren't as targeted as you may think that they are.

Comment: Why would limiting robocalling be nigh impossible?  Phone providers could be obliged to rate-limit outgoing (attempted) calls?

Comment: @gerrit: Robocallers would just use a larger number of phones to call from (Well, "Phones", but that distinction is sort of arbitrary.) - that, combined with the fact that politicians use the same type of setups to run phonebank campaigns means it'd be a no-go to rate-limit outgoing calls.

Comment: "Regulating the software technology to do that would be difficult" - rather than "difficult", a better description might be "possibly contrary to the interest of politicians". You mention some possible downsides, but these seem largely applicable to politicians rather than the general public (as much as I don't want to be called by scammers, I don't want to be called by politicians for fundraising campaigns or surveys), and downsides doesn't make something "difficult".

Comment: "cold calling is functionally the same as just calling a random 10-digit number" - this doesn't really make it non-viable. It seems one can easy classify dialing a bunch of random numbers as a public nuisance or something. This wouldn't be all that applicable to GDPR, but it seems one could easily make this illegal under other laws.

Comment: @NotThatGuy: That's a fair point about it being possibly contrary to the interest of politicians", but I will point out that classifying dialing a bunch of random numbers means you'd have to enforce calling wrong numbers (Off by a few, if just one, digit)...to the same effect as accidental [butt dials - sometimes to 911](https://youtu.be/A-XlyB_QQYs?t=649)l that's not solving the problem - that's re-classifying it. Your phone can, and will, dial nearly any 10 digit combination (Barring auto-shortcuts like 911), if that's what the user tries to do.

Comment: @AlexanderThe1st That's where intent and scale comes in. If someone occasionally calls a random or incorrect number, it's generally easy to argue that they didn't intend to do so, and they therefore shouldn't be charged with anything (some offenses require intent). If a company calls thousands of people, it's much harder to argue that they didn't intend to do so. Also, prosecuting someone for a single such offence would generally not be reasonable nor in line with the purpose of such a law (not that this would necessarily stop such prosecutions).

Comment: @AlexanderThe1st Where in the world do politicians legally use robocallers?  The only time I've ever had robocallers was in the UK, and the call was an obvious fraud/scam.  The rate of automated phonecalls is potentially orders of magnitudes higher than the rate of manual phonecalls, so it would be no problem to find a rate that allows a classic human-powered phone bank but disallows robocallers (I don't know how phone banks would get my number in a GDPR-compliant way, and indeed have never been targeted by one of those either).

Comment: You can rate limit, but some businesses may have a legitimate need to make lots of calls. Some companies legitimately do automated calls, like taxi companies or delivery companies alerting people; or businesses offering a call-back function to people who call in; providing codes for 2-factor authentication and potentially other alert services especially aimed at people without smartphones. And some companies offer centralised call services to many businesses, with vast call volumes. And it can be done from overseas, or simply by jumping from provider to provider.

Comment: @gerrit I've gotten robocalls from politicians all the time in the US.  Polling is exempt from many robocall laws in the US, so you get "pollsters" calling you with question like "A recent report has uncovered that Joe Biden murders kittens for fun.  Does this make you more or less likely to vote for him?".

Comment: @StuartF Of course, the rate limit can be raised for businesses with legitimate uses.

Comment: Disagree with this answer. Nobody's saying it needs to be a robot that blocks cold calls before they happen. It would be enough to put the perpetrators in jail. Just like cars don't stop you driving a bank robber away from the crime scene, neither should telephones stop you from calling to sell scams. In both cases the police track you down by other means (possibly including data recorded by the machines involved)

Comment: @gerrit: Robocalls are usually useful if what you want to do is contact a phone, and if you get their voicemail, leave a recorded message. You can connect the robocalling mechanism to a volunteer group so that when someone *does* pick up, you get transferred to a live person who can do further engagement (Turning it into an autodialer + robocaller combination), but robocalling helps increase the chances that the volunteer speaks to actual people, not voicemail machines.

Answer (score 4):

### Its a [spoofed](https://www.ofcom.org.uk/phones-telecoms-and-internet/advice-for-consumers/scams/phone-spoof-scam) number

So, you go to the police with the number they used. If it is a genuine number (which it may not be), the person who owns that number did not make the call. The police investigate and determine this is the case. Then what?

The scammer is in a country with no extradition treaty using a burner phone bought with a fake ID and used for a couple of weeks before being dumped. If you can’t find them, you can’t prosecute. If you can find them, you can’t prosecute because they are outside the reach of UK jurisdiction.

You can go into your phone handset right now and change the number that is displayed when you make calls - on an iPhone you do it through Settings->Phone->My Number.

This is a feature, not a bug. There are many legitimate reasons for changing this. For example, perhaps a company wants their sales team all use the same toll-free number and not to give out their individual moments. While this is a little less likely today, when caller ID was developed at the dawn of the mobile phone era, this would have been normal. So that’s how its designed.

Comment: This merely turns the question into "why is call spoofing permitted?". It would certainly be technically possible for phone companies to prevent it.

Comment: @DJClayworth why are phones permitted? Just because something can be used for an illegal purpose is not grounds for banning it when there are also legitimate purposes. An example of a legitimate use was provided in the answer.

Comment: I was told also that most of these numbers for forgeries, and they are operated from call centers outside of my country, so even if they could find out who did call, it's rather hard to prosecute them. IMHO establishing a framework where a caller could be identified eventually would be the solution on the long run. In the past with hard-wired phone lines, this wasn't much of a problem, but with Internet telephony these days, it's hard.

Comment: @DJClayworth Making the caller number reliable (hard to spoof) would require replacing basically the entire core telephone infrastructure with something completely different. Behind the scenes there's something called [Signalling System 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signalling_System_No._7) which is a system developed half a century ago. It treats numbers just like e-mail treats addresses: they're just random metadata slapped on, there's no fancy cryptography involved to authenticate them. You can't just replace this system without breaking interoperability with other networks worldwide.

Comment: … So it's basically a matter of just finding the weakest link. As long as there's at least one carrier somewhere which allows you to use an arbitrary number, scammers will just use that, no matter what the other carriers are doing.

Comment: In the US at least, there's a new law requiring phone companies to implement the STIR/SHAKEN protocol that in turn is supposed to make it easy to identify spoofed phone calls. https://www.fcc.gov/TRACEDAct

Comment: It seems that STIR/SHAKEN is designed to be implementable outside of the US as well, but maybe only Canada is currently doing so? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STIR/SHAKEN

Comment: The number seen by a recipient might be easy to spoof, but I can't imagine changing one's number in this way would present any obstacle whatsoever for law enforcement. You may not be able to stop people in an uncooperative country from making scam calls, but you can (a) potentially prevent those people from spoofing numbers or (b) block calls from that country altogether (which may sound extreme, but international politics require cooperation, so it's not that unreasonable to ostracise countries that refuse to cooperate). On paper, the problem presented here doesn't seem all that problematic.

Comment: I doubt there is still (strictly speaking) any technical reason to allow spoofing. For sales people not wanting to reveal their private numbers, I imagine there are a whole range of ways in which one can redirect one's calls to go through a line you own, without having to actually be in the same physical location (VPN has solved that problem a long time ago for redirecting internet connections).

Comment: @DJClayworth "why is call spoofing permitted?" Its actually very difficult to prevent. The signalling protocols for phone exchanges were developed decades ago when owning a phone exchange was expensive and rare, so they didn't bother with security. These days anyone can have one, but there is still zero security in the protocols. Fixing this would require a software upgrade in all exchanges globally, and ain't gonna happen.

Comment: I do not have an iPhone (but an Android phone), in Europe. You are saying that in your country you can put whatever number in your iPhone and it will be the caller ID that I will see? This cannot work in France at least.

Comment: @PaulJohnson: it can be fixed on the other side = your mobile operator. it would be enough for them to ensure that a call advertized from Nigeria actually comes from Nigeria. In this case you could trust the national prefix. In France you cannot spoof national numbers.

Comment: @DJClayworth Call spoofing has very legitimate reasons for existing. Legitimate businesses that use private branch exchanges (PBXs) **want** the caller ID to show the call came from that business. The same applies to legitimate business and individuals that use voice over internet protocol (VoIP).

Comment: @DavidHammen And it would be quite easy for the business or their telephone company to authenticate that the call came from the business, since it did. For anti-spoofing purposes all numbers at the business can be treated as the same, but not the same as the business next door, and not the same as one in Nigeria.

Comment: @TooTea The entire core telephone infrastructure has been replaced several times in the past, piecewise, so I find it hard to believe that a relatively small software upgrade is not possible. Telephone switches were built to speak to different types of telephone switches using different protocols (Connections Museum is very interesting) - it definitely shouldn't be impossible to make a system where caller ID is guaranteed *if all switches in the connection support it* and then add that feature to more and more switches. Since they are electronic now, should be just a software upgrade.

Comment: @user253751 “it would be very easy to authenticate” - not if employees use their own phones. Or for a large conglomerate if one company owns the phones but a dozen use them. Anyway, why should they or the phone company be put to the expense?

Comment: @DaleM because they don't want to be the source of scam calls. Or, because the government will fine them if they don't.

Comment: @user253751 you’re missing the point. Bank robbers use cars in committing their bank robberies - therefore we should ban cars. That is an exact analog of your argument that we should ban phone aliasing. Just because some bad actors can use a thing is not, of itself, an argument for banning it if it is benefiting many legitimate users. These things need to be balanced.

Comment: @DaleM That's why we should ban illegitimate phone aliasing and ban driving cars to or from a bank robbery... which we actually do - the driver becomes a criminal accomplice. And you're saying: well what if someone has to quickly move large amounts of money out of a bank vault under normal business operations? And the answer is: well the bank authorizes that (signs some paper if needed) and it's not a robbery. It's a complete non-problem.